# How to restrict user to access only his group elements in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, middleware, strongloop

I was trying to find it in docs or anywhere on the web but I did not find.

What I am asking about?
I am building website for multiple users. Frontend is not important, back backend API is being build in Loopback.
Every user will be assigned to some, let's name it GROUP.
Group content will be then exposed on subdomain but it is not important now.
Users will be kind of admins of their group.
I will have plenty of different models, but I will always have to protect user from accessing elements which not belongs to his group.

How should I do it? I think it will be some middleware but I do not know how to do it properly.
Of course, every user and every element have field "group_id".

Comment: I would consider a [dynamic role resolver(s)](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles). There is a [third-party loopback component package](https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-component-access-groups) available, which enables you to add multi-tenant style access controls. It's not perfect, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also trying to find a good solution... I did find this npm package that looks worth a try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-access-groups

Here is a short description of what the package is used for:

"This loopback component enables you to add multi-tenant style access controls to a loopback application. It enables you to restrict access to model data based on a user's roles within a specific context."

Comment: This solution is fine, but it overides the original ACL meaning that if you have an admin he/she won't be in charge anymore. It makes the entire application group-access-driven which can be tedious adding admins to every group.

Comment: There is a hack which sort of pawns a way for the admins: https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-component-access-groups/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggeling with the same problem, and I did not yet find a satisfatory response.

My workaround is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511149/how-can-i-filter-rest-calls-results-based-on-roles-and-current-user-context-in-l). I've got my user ID and with this, I retrieve the data I need to restrict the access. Then I alter the query in accordance with fetched data.